# Analysing DAC Spectra: Transient Noise Analysis

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, digital-to-analog, periodogram

I am working with a new Digital-to-Analog Converter (DAC) design in simulation and I'm trying to analyse the output. The device takes in an ideal 14-bit digital representation of a sine wave and outputs through an ideal Butterworth filter (a̶n̶t̶i̶-̶a̶l̶i̶a̶s̶i̶n̶g̶  anti-imaging).

In the simple analyses, I have been setting my input sinusoidal frequency such that it is coherent, and my sample capture length set up to collect 8196 points. I'm then running this through a simple MATLAB script that windows the simulation data and calculates the Welch periodogram using pwelch(), to reduce spectral leakage and variance respectively. Once I've done that, I'm measuring the characteristics of the device such as the SNR, SINAD (SNDR), THD and so on.

The next step in my analysis is slightly more complicated. I have run 5 transient noise simulations which result in 5 sets of output data, the only differences being the noise seen on the transient signal. How can I combine these spectra to get a more accurate picture of where the noise floor is in the device?

Assuming the noise is random, can I approach the situation similar to Bartlett's method but averaging across all 5 FFTs and creating a periodogram of the result?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean an anti-imaging filter, not anti-aliasing.

Comment: If you average the FFTs, you'll run into the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). It might be better to apply the calculatios on each spectrum, then average the results.

Comment: @Ben thanks you're right, more experience with ADCs so lazily applied the term, edited.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thanks, I'll give that a go! I think I might have been overcomplicating it....